# mkfs ext4 failing on Azure VM

Tags: linux, azure, centos

I have a VM running CenOS 6.3 on Azure. I'm following the steps in the Microsoft article to attach a disk ([article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/#attachexisting)).

When I run: sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
the process hangs indefinitely at "Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information"

If I start a new session and try mounting the partition it says:
"mount: you must specify the filesystem type"

I've upgraded and downgraded my VM in order to force a hardware switch. I've detached and re-attached new disks of various sizes. Same result each time.

I'm guessing it must be either an error or setting on my OS that is causing the problem. Below is a full bash session. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
[apper@apper ~]$ sudo grep SCSI /var/log/messages
Apr 19 14:08:47 apper kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 14:19:38 apper kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 19 14:22:58 apper kernel: SCSI subsystem initialized
Apr 19 14:22:58 apper kernel: Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
Apr 19 14:22:58 apper kernel: sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 14:22:58 apper kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 14:33:08 apper kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 14:40:16 apper kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 19 14:47:11 apper kernel: SCSI subsystem initialized
Apr 19 14:47:11 apper kernel: Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
Apr 19 14:47:11 apper kernel: sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 14:47:11 apper kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 14:48:40 apper kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[apper@apper ~]$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): n
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4): 1
First cylinder (1-32635, default 1):
Using default value 1
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (1-32635, default 32635):
Using default value 32635

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
[apper@apper ~]$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
16384000 inodes, 65535151 blocks
3276757 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
2000 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:
```

Answer (score 3):

Try passing `–E lazy_itable_init=1,lazy_journal_init=1` to `mkfs`.